# Sort a list of 'events' in Python

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

I have an event class:

```
def Event:
    def __init__(self, start, end, rule, location, summary):
        ...
        #start, end, and rule are datetime.datetime objects
        #location and summary are strings
```

I have an array of Events which I want to sort by `start`, then by `location`

Currently I'm sorting them by `start` like so:

```
events.sort(key=lambda e: e.start)
```

How do I sort by location (alphanumerically, since its a string) after by start?

Comment: `events.sort(key=lambda e: (e.start, e.location))`

Answer (score 7):

You just need the key to be a tuple. Leveraging the natural sorting order of tuples.

```
events.sort(key=lambda e: (e.start, e.location))
```

This doesn't *need* to be a lambda function. In fact sometimes it's better to use a named function so you can unittest it. eg.

```
def start_location_key(e):
    return e.start, e.location

events.sort(key=start_location_key)
```

In your case you can even use attrgetter

```
from operator import attrgetter
events.sort(key=attrgetter('start', 'location'))
```

All these work equally well. However the second one is more flexible - you can add an exception handler/debug it/etc. much more easily.